# Interactive software diagrams or charting tool

Tags: software-development, drawing, charts, diagram, component-diagram

I want to create several documents that map/describe my company's Software Systems.
What are the recommended tools for that ?

I have been using [draw.io](http://draw.io) (non interactive).
Have stumbled across [SmartDiagrams](https://www.smartdraw.com/diagrams/), which offer examples of various type of such diagrams.

1. Any tool that offers drill downs - i.e., clicking into a component and navigating into a new view/diagram ? Or offer other types of interactions ?
2. Free tools are preferable, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Visio quite a bit for similar software diagraming, however I don't believe that has a drill-down option.

Comment: Thanks. Visio is probably the most known. I am seeking something free, though.

Answer (score 0):

A friend just shared with me that VS 2022 offers built in support for [Architecture Analysis & Modeling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/analyze-and-model-your-architecture?view=vs-2022).

1. [Install architecture code tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/install-architecture-tools?view=vs-2022)
2. [Visualize dependencies with code maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/map-dependencies-across-your-solutions?view=vs-2022)

**Problem**: creating code maps requires VS Enterprise edition.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A good tool for diagrams is [yED](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) which is freely available and over time has been expanded with some additional tools and features